# Get Value of XML Node

Tags: xml, simplexml

I am traversing through an xml file. I successfully read through all the nodes but when i try to access the value of that attribute, it returns empty object.

If I run the following code

```
$xml_data=simplexml_load_file($path . $files);
print_r($xml_data->CONFIRMATION->FILEID);
die;
```

This returns

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 002796.20140501.133002.314307 )
```

But when i try to get that exact value using the following code

```
 $xml_data=simplexml_load_file($path . $files);
 print_r($xml_data->CONFIRMATION->FILEID[0]);
 die;
```

I get

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Any ideas how can I get that exact string of numbers within that node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is there as shown by the `print_r($xml_data->CONFIRMATION->FILEID)`. I don't know about the `print_r` printing the individual nodes of the array, but you certainly can assign the data or print it normally.

This should work:

```
echo $xml_data->CONFIRMATION->FILEID[0]."\n";
```

You should also be able to loop:

```
foreach($xml_data->CONFIRMATION->FILEID as $fileid) {
    echo '<p>'.$fileid.'</p>'."\n";
}
```